# How to fgets from two sources in PHP?

Tags: php, pipe

I have some code that interacts with FFMpeg through `proc_open` and `fgets`. I have 2 pipes - `stdout` and `sterr`. I need to simultaneously read text from them both.
My current code:

```
if ($ffmpeg->startProcess()) {
    echo '<pre>';
    while ($s = fgets($ffmpeg->pipes[2])) {
        print  $s . '<br>';
        flush();
    }
    echo '</pre>';
    echo 'Reconverted ' . $file . '<br>';
} else echo 'Error staring process... File skipped';
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. When would you get a `sterr` at the same time as `stdout`? If `stdout` is being used, then there should be no error. If there is an error, then there would be no output. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I guess, ffmpeg uses both stout and stderr for output. Nevertheless, I have solved this problem by redirecting this pipes to file and reading from it